# Any affine variety corresponds to an open subset of projective space?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $Y$ be an affine variety of $\mathbb{A}^n$. I read in a previous question that then $Y$ can be identified with an open subset of projective space $\mathbb{P}^n$.

I don't know why this is true as it is not stated in my notes.

However, in the red book it mentions that projective space can be covered by $(n+1)$ subsets $U_0, \dots U_n$ where each $U_i$ is a set of homogeneous coordinates and each $U_i$ is naturally isomorphic to $k^n$

1. Why can we cover projective space by such subsets ? It makes some intuitive sense as adding points of infinity would make the space compact. However, it would be nice to see some concrete reasoning for this.
2. Is my first statement related to this covering of $\mathbb{P}^n$ and how?

Comment: I'm getting ahead of myself: what kind of answer do you want for (1)? Mumford surely writes down the maps. Do you want motivation for working in projective space?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $\mathbf A^n$ can be considered an open subspace of $\mathbf P^n$, for instance with the correspondence:
\begin{align*}
\mathbf A^n&\longrightarrow\mathbf P^n\\
(x_1,\dots,x_n)&\longmapsto (1:x_1:\dots:x_n)
\end{align*}
The inverse correspondence is defined on $\mathbf P^n\smallsetminus H_0$, where $H_0$ is the hyperplane $x_0=0$:
\begin{align*}
\mathbf P^n\smallsetminus H_0&\longrightarrow\mathbf A^n\\
 (x_0:x_1:\dots:x_n)&\longmapsto\Bigl(\frac{x_1}{x_0},\dots,\frac{x_n}{x_0}\Bigr)
\end{align*}
Actually, one can show the complement of any hyperplane in $\mathbf P^n$ is isomorphic to $\mathbf A^n$.